# Mysql: LIKE + NOT LIKE < ALL

Tags: mysql

Can't understand such results:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) count FROM `persons_tmp` WHERE `p`.`medical_result1` NOT LIKE '%СО%6%'

Result: 36191

SELECT COUNT(*) count FROM `persons_tmp` WHERE `p`.`medical_result1` LIKE '%СО%6%'

Result: 140

SELECT COUNT(*) count FROM `persons_tmp`

Result: 42360
```

36191 + 140 < 42360. What's wrong?

Comment: try to make minus between those results and see what you're getting

Comment: @RoeyGolzarpoor, I believe you were on par with Joe Philllips answer below.  Gave you the upvote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not counting null values because null essentially means "unknown". If it doesn't know the value, it can't do a comparison so it simply ignores those rows.

Try this to see if it makes up the difference:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) count FROM `persons_tmp` WHERE `p`.`medical_result1` IS NULL
```

Comment: ... you beat me to it by mere seconds.  You're getting the up-vote.

Comment: @Steiner Me too, I was just about to post that. Hacks.